Angular service is not making HTTP request for testing

api.service.ts

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, from, map, of, switchMap, tap, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { GithubRepository, GithubUser } from '../types/GithubAPIType';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ApiService {
  cacheName: string = 'github-cache';
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getUser(githubUsername: string): Observable<GithubUser> {
    const url = `https://api.github.com/users/${githubUsername}`;

    return from(this.getCachedResponse<GithubUser>(url)).pipe(
      switchMap((cachedResponse) => {
        if (cachedResponse) {
          return of(cachedResponse);
        } else {
          return this.httpClient.get<GithubUser>(url).pipe(
            tap((response) => {
              this.cacheResponse(url, response);
            })
          );
        }
      })
    );
  }

  // implement getRepos method by referring to the documentation. Add proper types for the return type and params
  getRepos(
    githubUsername: string,
    per_page?: number,
    page_number?: number
  ): Observable<GithubRepository[]> {
    const url = `https://api.github.com/users/${githubUsername}/repos?per_page=${per_page}&page=${page_number}`;

    return from(this.getCachedResponse<GithubRepository[]>(url)).pipe(
      switchMap((cachedResponse) => {
        if (cachedResponse) {
          return of(cachedResponse);
        } else {
          return this.httpClient.get<GithubRepository[]>(url).pipe(
            tap((response) => {
              this.cacheResponse(url, response);
            })
          );
        }
      })
    );
  }

  // Retrieve data from cache
  async getCachedResponse<T>(request: string): Promise<T | null> {
    const cache = await caches.open(this.cacheName);
    const cachedResponse = await cache.match(request);
    if (cachedResponse) {
      return cachedResponse.json();
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  test(): Observable<GithubUser> {
    return this.httpClient.get<GithubUser>(
      'https://api.github.com/users/mohammedvaraliya'
    );
  }
  // Store data to the cache
  async cacheResponse(request: string, response: any): Promise<void> {
    const cache = await caches.open(this.cacheName);
    const clonedResponse = new Response(JSON.stringify(response));
    await cache.put(request, clonedResponse);
  }
}


api.service.spec.ts

import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { ApiService } from './api.service';
import {
  HttpClientTestingModule,
  HttpTestingController,
} from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { mockUser } from 'src/mocks/mockData';

describe('ApiService', () => {
  let service: ApiService;
  let httpController: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [ApiService],
      teardown: { destroyAfterEach: false },
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(ApiService);
    httpController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);

    // Mock the caches object and getCachedResponse method
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'caches', {
      value: {
        open: () => Promise.resolve({ match: () => Promise.resolve(null) }),
      },
    });

    // Mock the getCachedResponse method
    spyOn(service, 'getCachedResponse').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(null));
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    httpController.verify(); // Verify that there are no outstanding requests
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('shoud return correct user data', () => {
    console.log('Testing ');
    service.getUser('mohammedvaraliya').subscribe({
      next: (user) => {
        console.log(user);
        expect(user).toBe(mockUser);
      },
      error: () => console.log('Error'),

      complete: () => console.log('Completed'),
    });
    const req = httpController.expectOne(
      'https://api.github.com/users/mohammedvaraliya'
    );

    req.flush(mockUser);
  });
});

The problem here is the service works wells in regular usage but whenever I run tests on it gives the following error:
" Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL: https://api.github.com/users/mohammedvaraliya", found none."
I am new angular please help me with this, thank you.
I tried removing the caching process and then it starts working, but with caching it does not works.

So a few things, first of all, although it's not the cause of your problem, your unit test is bound to fail, as it is asynchronous, the test will not wait for the resolution before executing the next one.
You can "mark" a test as asynchronous by using the DoneFn callback in your unit test, and calling it when the test should be considered finished :
// Pass the "done" parameter to the test function
it('shoud return correct user data', (done) => {
  console.log('Testing ');
  service.getUser('mohammedvaraliya').subscribe({
    next: (user) => {
      expect(user).toEqual(mockUser);
      // We did our assertion, use the DoneFn callback to mark the test as finished
      done();
    },
    error: () => console.log('Error'),

    complete: () => console.log('Completed'),
  });
  const req = httpController.expectOne(
    'https://api.github.com/users/mohammedvaraliya'
  );

  req.flush(mockUser);
});

But your test is failing due to the mocking of the getCachedResponse function, using Promise.resolve(null) seems to instantaneously resolve the promise.
I'm not entireley sure why this doesn't work in this case if it is working in your application, but this causes a problem with the Observable in your getUser function, as it will neither try to get the cached data nor try to call the api:
getUser(githubUsername: string): Observable<GithubUser> {
  const url = `https://api.github.com/users/${githubUsername}`;
  return from(this.getCachedResponse<GithubUser>(url)).pipe(
    // Code here is never called
  );
}

I failed to find any easy way to fix this, so I will offer you a solution that may not be the best for your use case :
I fixed it by updated the getCachedResponse to return an Observable instead of a Promise :
api.service.ts
getUser(githubUsername: string): Observable<GithubUser> {
  const url = `https://api.github.com/users/${githubUsername}`;
  return this.getCachedResponse<GithubUser>(url).pipe(
    switchMap((cachedResponse) => {
      // Logic here...
    })
  );
}

getCachedResponse<T>(request: string): Observable<T | null> {
  const cache = from(caches.open(this.cacheName));
  return cache.pipe(
    switchMap(async (cache) => {
      const cachedResponse = await cache.match(request);
      if (cachedResponse) {
        return cachedResponse.json();
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    })
  );
} 

api.service.spec.ts
beforeEach( () => {
  // TestBed configuration

  // Mock the getCachedResponse method
  spyOn(service, 'getCachedResponse').and.returnValue(of(null));
  spyOn(service, 'cacheResponse');
});

Even though it may require more changes that you'd like to do, I'd say that I would rather not mix up Promises and Observables in the way you did, as it can often lead to all sorts of errors that can be hard to debug.
I hope this helps.

Thank you for clearing my doubt. It works now, but could can you suggest me the best approach to handle this type of tasks.
